# ERROR directory does not exist

Tags: server, xubuntu

HI Everyone so i made this directory called folder
using mkdir folder in ubuntu server 16 LTS 
whenever i do an ls command the directory is there
but whenever i cd it tells me the directory does not exist
please help

Comment: Does the directory contain spaces (or special characters)?  If so you should escape the unusual characters, or quote the directory.  Copying and pasting (into the question) your problem would allow us to be more specific*, and if its Ubuntu server, it's not Xubuntu (your tag doesn't match text)*

Comment: sorry yes its ubuntu server. and no there isnt any spaces involved